# MySQL - different partial ORDERING (based on time)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a list of events on my site, some are in the future, some are past ones.

The thing is, I want to apply different ORDER, I think it's best I explain my situation with the following example. Let's say I'm on the page with the list of events, and it gives me the following:

```
// Today's events:
A 17:00
B 19:00
C 20:00
// Yesterday's events:
D 21:00
E 18:00
F 09:00
```

So as you can see, when I fetch 6 events, I want to apply different order for the future events and past events. If I'm looking at a future event, I want at the top the event that's earliest, which is followed by events that are going to happen later.

When I look at past events, at the top I want latest event (closer to current time), which is followed by earlier events (more far than current time).

Currently I'm doing two queries (PHP), one to get first X events, and if I'm missing some events to reach that limit X, I would query again the database and get some past events.

Those are two queries, I was wondering if it could be done in one query, for which I could possibly also set offset/limit (pagination).

UPDATED:
I'm sorry for not putting my code example, the reason I didn't put any was because SELECT statement is really simple. I have something like this:

```
 SELECT id, title, datetime FROM events;
```

The only thing I can add here is that I used two statements, one for future events and one for past events (I would execute those one by one using PHP):

```
 SELECT id, title, datetime FROM events WHERE datetime > NOW() ORDER BY datetime ASC;
```

and for past events, I would use of course

```
 SELECT id, title, datetime FROM events WHERE datetime <= NOW() ORDER BY datetime DESC;
```

Also, what I also mentioned, I would execute first statement, and if total limit is 10, and I received only 5 events, I would then execute 2nd statment with a limit 5, just to reach those 10 events I wanted initially.

Thank you!

---

Resolved, this is the final result:

```
 SELECT id, datetime, IF(datetime > NOW(), 1, 0) inFuture
 FROM icm_event
 ORDER BY inFuture DESC,
 (CASE WHEN inFuture = 1 THEN datetime END) ASC,
 (CASE WHEN inFuture = 0 THEN datetime END) DESC
```

Thank you Gordon Linoff :)

Comment: Order by x>now() DESC

Comment: The question would be a lot clearer with some example queries.

Comment: This is a very poor example of a question please show code to support question here what are you trying to say..???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a clever `order by`:

```
select *
from table t
order by (eventdate = curdate()) desc,                               -- put today's events first
         (case when eventdate = curdate() then eventtime end) asc,   -- order today in ascending order
         (case when eventdate <> curdate() then eventtime end) desc; -- order the rest in descending order
```

You don't give much information on the structure of the table, but the above idea should work, although the details may differ for your table.

Comment: Thank you, this really worked, this is my final query:
     SELECT id, datetime, IF(datetime > NOW(), 1, 0) inFuture                                                               
     FROM event                                                                                                         
     ORDER BY inFuture DESC, 
     (CASE WHEN inFuture = 1 THEN datetime END) ASC, 
     (CASE WHEN inFuture = 0 THEN datetime END) DESC

Answer (score 1):

Try to use select command two time and use  " Union All " to show all of the result.

Eg.

```
Select * from (Select * from xxx where ... order by time ASC) as tb1
Union All
Select * from (Select * from xxx where ... order by time DESC) as tb2
```

Hope this will help.